# Find the area of the curved shape

Tags: geometry, intuition

How to find area of this curved shape?

[image: curved shape]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the left and right boundaries of your region can be represented by equations of the form $x = f(y)$ and $x = g(y)$ for $0 \le y \le 16$.  Then your area is $\int_0^{16} (g(y) - f(y))\ dy$.  It also looks like $g(y) - f(y)$ is approximately (but not exactly) $4 + X$, so the area is approximately $16 (4 + X)$.

Answer (score 0):

If the claim is that the cross-sections are all $4+x$ wide, then by [Cavalieri's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle) the area is $16(4+x)$.